# Byte[] to Bitmap vs Bitmap to byte[]: Which is Faster?

Tags: java, android

Sure, I could write something to work this out but, due to this thing called idleness I was wondering whether somone else might have the answer, which may save me some time.

I have a `CursorAdapter` class. In `bindView` it needs to verify some `byte[]` data from the cursor so I can decide whether to update a field or not.

As the bindView needs be very fast is the process of turning an existing (`ImageView` drawable) `Bitmap` into a `byte[]` going to be faster and less resource intensive that turning an `byte[]` (cursor data) into a `Bitmap`?

The result either way is for the purpose of comparison.

**Edit:**
Further to my question, I am aware that you should load `Bitmap`s off the UI thread, but should you also compress a `Bitmap` to `byte[]` off the UI thread? Or is this not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion is likely going to be the same performance wise, but comparing primitives is generally going to be faster than comparing Objects.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose my main quandary is that I know I need to perform the loading (decoding) of bitmaps off the main UI thread, but should the compressing of a bitmap drawable also be performed off the UI thread?

Comment: @Haraldo I'd recommend doing it off the UI thread. Images can get pretty computationally intensive.

Comment: Just to labour the point, I already have the `ImageView` `drawable`. So is your answer still accurate for turning this `drawable`/`bitmap` to a `byte[]`? Or should this process still be performed off the UI?

Comment: @Haraldo `Drawable` wraps a `Bitmap` object, which is what you'll actually be converting to a `byte[]`, so I'd still recommend doing it off the UI thread, because on slower device it may take a while.